# 3ds Max to three.js - How to export simple animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, 3dsmax

I have a very basic scene in 3ds Max with a single `cube` and a single `animation`. The animation only moves the box from `position A` to `position B`. No morph target animation, no bones etc. Just plain "movement" animation.

Below are the two keyframes present. The first image is at keyframe 0, the second at keyframe 30. You can see that the box moved between these keyframes.

[image]
[image]

Now I export my `cube` to the OBJ format and convert that `.obj` file to a `.js` file using the [python converter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py).

[The example I used](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-export-a-rigged-animated-model-from-3ds-max-three-js/) stated that there should be an `animations` (or `animation`) property on the `geometry`, like so:

```
var animation = new THREE.Animation(
    animatedMesh,
    geometry.animation // this line
);
```

However, my converted `js` file does not have the simple animation I added in 3ds, hence `geometry.animation` returns `undefined` in my example. The `.js` file looks like so:

```
{

"metadata" :
{
    "formatVersion" : 3.1,
    "sourceFile"    : "box4.obj",
    "generatedBy"   : "OBJConverter",
    "vertices"      : 8,
    "faces"         : 6,
    "normals"       : 6,
    "colors"        : 0,
    "uvs"           : 4,
    "materials"     : 1
},

"scale" : 1.000000,

"materials": [  {
"DbgColor" : 15658734,
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName" : "wire_061135006",
"colorDiffuse" : [0.2392, 0.5294, 0.0235],
"colorSpecular" : [0.35, 0.35, 0.35],
"illumination" : 2,
"opacity" : 1.0,
"specularCoef" : 32.0
}],

"vertices": [35.029700,0.000000,-19.238000,35.029700,0.000000,-45.844600,45.055000,0.000000,-45.844600,45.055000,0.000000,-19.238000,35.029700,18.650700,-19.238000,45.055000,18.650700,-19.238000,45.055000,18.650700,-45.844600,35.029700,18.650700,-45.844600],

"morphTargets": [],

"morphColors": [],

"normals": [0,-1,-0,0,1,-0,0,0,1,1,0,-0,0,0,-1,-1,0,-0],

"colors": [],

"uvs": [[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]],

"faces": [43,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,43,4,5,6,7,0,3,0,1,2,1,1,1,1,43,0,3,5,4,0,3,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,43,3,2,6,5,0,3,0,1,2,3,3,3,3,43,2,1,7,6,0,3,0,1,2,4,4,4,4,43,1,0,4,7,0,3,0,1,2,5,5,5,5]
```

}

In the export window for OBJ, I don't see an option to include animations like there is in the FBX export window.

**So, how do I export that simple movement animation from 3ds and bake it into my `.js` file?**